# What are some ways to securely authorize Okta users to self service onboard integrations

Tags: okta, okta-api

**Use case**: Enable self-service OIDC and SAML integrations for application admins within enterprise

I am wondering what are all the ways to securely authorize application admins within an enterprise to self-service integrate their applications with Okta for authentication. I am aware that Okta APIs will allow this but am concerned about over-provisioning of permissions. Ideally I would like to allow anyone to integrate their SAMl/OIDC applications with Okta and modify them in future, but restrict them from modifying applications they do not own.